# what hardware should I use for wheel encoders

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am building a differential drive robot from an old powered wheelchair. The wheels are attached to the motor by a ~10:1 gearbox. I would like to add encoders to the motors.  what kind of encoders should I use. I am running a full PC onboard. I have a chip kit max32 that I could use as an interface. What is the best way to add encoders. Is there a useful usb interface? What kind resolution should I look at. The motor drivers I am using do not have encoder feedback. Thanks for any feedback.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52131/what-hardware-should-i-use-for-wheel-encoders./) by [packrat](https://answers.ros.org/users/3685/packrat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2013-01-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [packrat](https://answers.ros.org/users/3685/packrat/) on 2013-01-13**:
At full power the robot can move about town miles an hour. Is it typical to use a dedicated device just to read the encoders?  A device like"http://www.robotshop.com/phidgets-phidgetencoder-highspeed-usb-4-input-2.html"

**Comment by [packrat](https://answers.ros.org/users/3685/packrat/) on 2013-01-14**:
My other question is, what hardware do you guys recommend. 200 CPR encoder connected to an arduino?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The encoder resolution depends on ur system demands,i.e, how fast do u want ur robot to go. If u need excellent low speed characteristics, it's better to have high resolution encoders. From the situation u've explained, I suggest u can use an ARM development board with high speed IOs to read the pulses outputted by the encoders, and communicate with ur PC via serial port like RS232.

---

Originally posted by [Kent](https://answers.ros.org/users/3533/kent/) with karma: 140 on 2013-01-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0